# Error parsing JSON data, org.json.jsonexception, java.lang.String can not be converted

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I've got an error in the LogCat when I'm trying to update a score via PHP to MYSQL.
The given error:
"Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value < form of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject".
I'm quite new to this so I don't know how to fix this...

Here is my code:

**Android code for updating the score:**

```
int scoreEL;
String username;


if(DifficultyMenu.scoreEL1 < scoreEL1){
            new UpdateScores().execute();

        }




class UpdateScores extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       int success;
       try {
           List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
           params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
           params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stars", String.valueOf(scoreEL1)));

           Log.d("request!", "starting");

           JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                  LOGIN_URL_1, "POST", params);

           Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

           success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
           if (success == 1) {
            Log.d("Updated successful!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));

            finish();
            return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
           }else{
            Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
            return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

           }
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

       return null;

 }
```

**JSONParser class:**

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}


public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(final String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // Construct the client and the HTTP request.
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        // Execute the POST request and store the response locally.
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        // Extract data from the response.
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        // Open an inputStream with the data content.
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        // Create a BufferedReader to parse through the inputStream.
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        // Declare a string builder to help with the parsing.
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        // Declare a string to store the JSON object data in string form.
        String line = null;

        // Build the string until null.
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        // Close the input stream.
        is.close();
        // Convert the string builder data to an actual string.
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // Try to parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // Return the JSON Object.
    return jObj;

}


// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

}

**PHPcode:**

```
<?php
if($_POST['submit']){

$stars= $_POST['stars'];
$username = $_POST['username'];

$connect = mysql_connect("*****", "****", "*****") or die("Can't connect to database!");
mysql_select_db("a9698368_webserv") or die("Can't select database!");

try{

    $checkUsername = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username =      '$username'");
    $checkuser = mysql_fetch_assoc($checkUsername);
    if($username == $checkuser){
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "User doesn't exist!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error. Please Try Again!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}


try{

mysql_query("
UPDATE users SET easy_level1 = '$stars' WHERE username = '$username'
");
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error. Please Try Again!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

try{
$check = mysql_query("
SELECT easy_level1 FROM users WHERE username = '$username'
");
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Can't check if the new score is successfully updated!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

if($check !== $stars){
    $updated = true;
}

if ($updated) {
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Updated successful!";
    die(json_encode($response));
} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Can't update the stars!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

mysql_close();

}
else{

echo"
<form action='updateEL1.php' method='POST'>
Username: <input type='text' name='username'><br>
Stars: <input type='text' name='stars'><br>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Update'>
</form>
";
}
?>
```

Can somebody help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: paste your stacktrace and your JSON too

Comment: And additionally, try to pin it down to a much shorter piece of code. I very much doubt that you need ~250 lines to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bad designed for API, I wonder who wrote this tutorial, Everytime I see someone use it it's the same issue occuring.

You are writing an android app, there should be no HTML involved, when the field are missing you should still return json data and **not** HTML form.

Read the error carefully:

> "Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value **< form** of type
>   java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject"

Yes form is the html tag, and that means the condition was not met.

Then if you look at the condition

```
if($_POST['submit'])
```

That will never be true because you dont have an html submit button in your app.

You should be checking if the value you sent by the app are set, if not send back a json response error stating that.

---

```
<?php
$response = array();

if(isset($_POST['stars'], $_POST['username'])){

    $stars= $_POST['stars'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];

    $connect = mysql_connect("*****", "****", "*****") or die("Can't connect to database!");
    mysql_select_db("a9698368_webserv") or die("Can't select database!");

    try{
        $query = sprintf("UPDATE users SET easy_level1 ='%s' WHERE username ='%s'",
                                     mysql_real_escape_string($stars),
                                     mysql_real_escape_string($username));
        mysql_query($query);
    }
    catch (Exception $ex) {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error. Please Try Again!";
    }


    if ( mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Updated successful!";
    } else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Can't update the stars!";
    }
    mysql_close();

}
else{
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Missing post data!";
}
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reaction, you're right! The button is never clicked... I never thought about that! Thankyou very much! i wil edit the code!

Comment: If you want to thank me ease accept the answer

Comment: Done, I'll change the code for the button right now!

Comment: I've changed the if($_POST['submit']) to if(!empty($_POST)) but it still doesn't work in the app... But if I go to my site and click submit, it does work... You know how to fix this?

Comment: because you never echo the JSON, and why do you run these SELECT statemnet

Comment: For checking if the user exist, is that not necessary?

Comment: Actually Ive already deleted that! I don't see it in my code anymore. Maybe I also thought that it wouldm't be necessary. But thanks again for your help!

Comment: see my edit please, I made some changes, I dont know why you were catching PDOException if you are using deprecated

Comment: Thankyou very much!! I don't know PHP that much so I copied and paste things from some tutorials...

Comment: It didn't work, I don't know why, but your php-code seems to be good, I'll run it tomorrow in eclipse en see what the LogCat shows me for information. And then when I'm home from school I'll send another message to let you know what I know! I'm going to sleep. Bye! Thanks for helping another time!:)

Comment: welcome bro just let me know

Comment: I'm sorry today I wasn't able to go on my pc. Maybe tomorrow evening (Dutch time).

Comment: sure I am alway around

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I can do it in about a half our. Otherwise I'll do it deffinately tomorrow!